# How can I remove relative path components but leave symlinks alone in Perl?

Tags: perl, path, realpath

I need to get Perl to remove relative path components from a Linux path.  I've found a couple of functions that almost do what I want, but:

`File::Spec->rel2abs` does too little.  It does not resolve ".." into a directory properly.

`Cwd::realpath` does too much.  It resolves all symbolic links in the path, which I do not want.

Perhaps the best way to illustrate how I want this function to behave is to post a bash log where FixPath is a hypothetical command that gives the desired output:

```
'/tmp/test'$ mkdir -p a/b/c1 a/b/c2
'/tmp/test'$ cd a
'/tmp/test/a'$ ln -s b link
'/tmp/test/a'$ ls
b  link
'/tmp/test/a'$ cd b
'/tmp/test/a/b'$ ls
c1  c2
'/tmp/test/a/b'$ FixPath . # rel2abs works here
===> /tmp/test/a/b
'/tmp/test/a/b'$ FixPath .. # realpath works here
===> /tmp/test/a
'/tmp/test/a/b'$ FixPath c1 # rel2abs works here
===> /tmp/test/a/b/c1
'/tmp/test/a/b'$ FixPath ../b # realpath works here
===> /tmp/test/a/b
'/tmp/test/a/b'$ FixPath ../link/c1 # neither one works here
===> /tmp/test/a/link/c1
'/tmp/test/a/b'$ FixPath missing # should work for nonexistent files
===> /tmp/test/a/b/missing
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not going to find what you need exactly.  Why do you need the links left alone?  Also, how are you going to deal with a symlink that includes ./../../bin/twiddle/../there where, in fact, twiddle is a symlink that does /arbitrary/other/path (or arbitrary/path/from/here).  Also, what do you want it to do with cycles in the symlink paths, or other such.

Comment: I'm fine with the solution being broken for those cases (e.g. `./../../bin/twiddle/../there` becomes `/tmp/test/bin/there` in my example).  It shouldn't ever need to read symlinks.  If such a function doesn't exist (I am beginning to see why...) then I'll work on writing it.

Comment: If you just want to translate "foo/../bar" to "bar", then do that -- but this is not a filesystem operation that makes sense in general; hence the lack of support.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it will help, but if you go to the IIUG web site (http://www.iiug.org/software) and find 'linkpath' in the repository, you will find ... code that achieves the effect of `realpath` but which evaluates the security of each step in the path.  You will also find some extremely contorted sets of symlinks; the torture test I put it through is (mostly) in there too. It might be a basis for what you need - it might not. I don't pretend it is the greatest code in the world. However, I've not found a circumstance where it fails unreasonably--but there's always what you invent!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, here is what I came up with:

```
sub mangle_path {
  # NOT PORTABLE
  # Attempt to remove relative components from a path - can return
  # incorrect results for paths like ../some_symlink/.. etc.

  my $path = shift;
  $path = getcwd . "/$path" if '/' ne substr $path, 0, 1;

  my @dirs = ();
  for(split '/', $path) {
    pop @dirs, next if $_ eq '..';
    push @dirs, $_ unless $_ eq '.' or $_ eq '';
  }
  return '/' . join '/', @dirs;
}
```

I know this is possibly insecure and invalid, but any input to this routine will come from me on the command line, and it solves a couple of tricky use cases for me.

Comment: Right now I could not care less about portability for this app.  If I change my mind, I've marked places in the code that I know would need to be changed.